# Trouble with byte array marshaling in ObjC/C++ to C# in IOS

Tags: c++, arrays, ios, xamarin.ios, marshalling

** This is still unsolved **

I'm trying to call an ObjC/C++ function code from C#. I've done my best to follow different example code, the latest being mostly from:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146631(v=VS.80).aspx

This is for an iPhone/MonoTouch environment, so I'm not sure I've done everything I should. The bytes appear to be ok in the ObjC/C++ function, but the byte array I get back into C# ends up containing  0 0 0 0 0 0 etc.

** Update **

Corrected for loop initializer, and now its giving a EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal on the *returnbytes[i] = bytes[i]; line.

C# code:

```
[DllImport ("__Internal")]
private static extern int _getjpeg(string url,ref IntPtr thebytes); 

void somefunction(string image_id) {
    int maxsize = 50000;

    byte[] thebytes = new byte[maxsize];
    IntPtr byteptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(maxsize);

    int imagesize = _getjpeg(image_id,ref byteptr);

    Debug.Log("Getting _picturesize()... "+ image_id);
    int picsize = _picturesize(); 

    Marshal.Copy(byteptr,thebytes,0,picsize);   

    var texture = new Texture2D(1,1);

    string bytedebug = "";
    for (int i=5000 ; i < 5020 ; i++)
        bytedebug+=thebytes[i] + " ";

    Debug.Log("Bytes length is "+imagesize);
    Debug.Log("Bytes content is "+bytedebug);
}
```

C++/ObjC code:

```
int _getjpeg(const char* url,unsigned char** returnbytes) {

    ALAsset* asset = [_pictures objectForKey:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:url]];

    if(asset != NULL)
        NSLog(@"_getjpeg() found URL: %@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String: url]);
    else {
        NSLog(@"_getjpeg() could not find URL: %@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String: url]);
        return NULL;
    }

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: [asset thumbnail]];
    NSData* pictureData =  UIImageJPEGRepresentation (image, 1.0);

    picturesize = (int)[pictureData length];

    unsigned char* bytes = (unsigned char*)[pictureData bytes];

    // This test does not give EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    *returnbytes[5] = (unsigned int)3;

    // updated below initializer in below for loop according to Eikos suggestion
    for(int i=0 ; i < picturesize ; i++) {
        // below lines gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS
        *returnbytes[i] = bytes[i];            
    }

    NSString* debugstr  = [NSString string];

    for(int i=5000; i < 5020 ; i++) {
        unsigned char byteint = bytes[i];
        debugstr = [debugstr stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i ",byteint]];

    }


    NSLog(@"bytes %s",[debugstr UTF8String]);
    return picturesize;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the `JPGRepresentation` is probably not exactly the same as you put into it, so the length may differ.

In

```
for(int i;i < picturesize;i++) {
    // *** Not sure I'm doing this correctly ***
    *returnbytes[i] = bytes[i];            
}
```

you forget to initialize `i`, so it might start with a random value which is bigger than `picturesize`, so the loop won't run at all.

Comment: Thanks, that was quite dumb of me. Corrected it and now it's giving a EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal on the *returnbytes[i] = bytes[i]; line.

Comment: I should think so. I initialized it in C#. Tried a few sized in C#. The last one was:   IntPtr byteptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(500000 * Marshal.SizeOf(samplearray[0]));
  
  int imagesize = _getjpeg(image_id,ref byteptr);

Comment: Did another test without the for loop: *returnbytes[5] = (unsigned int)3; does not produce the EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal.

Answer (score 0):

You want `unsigned char*`, not `**`. You are passing a pointer in that is already allocated. A `**` is for when you are passing in a pointer to variable that is itself a pointer to data: i.e. when the callee will allocate the memory and the caller wants to know about it.

Just pass in unsigned char* and then use

```
returnbytes[i] = bytes[i];
```

Alternatively, allocate in the calee and use an out, not a ref.